# Accessing treechildren in xul for styling

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul

I have this code in xul:

```xml
<treechildren id = "mainTree_treechildren">
    <treeitem container="true" open="true">
        <treerow>
           <treecell label="&tree.actions;" />
        </treerow>
        <treechildren id="tree_actions_treechildren" >
            <treeitem container="true" open="true">
                <treerow>
                     <treecell label="&tree.actions.warnings;" />
                </treerow>
            </treeitem>
        </treechildren>
     </treeitem>
</treechildren>
```

and i have problem styling it. I need to have to different text colors for treecell in `mainTree_treechildren` and different text color for treecell in his child treechildren with id `tree_actions_treechildren`.

At the moment I have this css code

```css
#mainTree #mainTree_treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text { color: #000000; }
#mainTree #tree_actions_treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text { color: #FFFFFF; }
```

But it doesn't work. I only get black color for every element inside  `mainTree_treechildren` including `tree_actions_treechildren`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<treechildren>` elements aren't actually being displayed - they are merely the data source for the tree widget (other data sources are also possible, e.g. RDF or XML files). Consequently, their contents cannot be styled directly. If you want to style individual tree cells differently you should use the [`properties` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/treecell#a-properties). Something like this should work:

```xml
<treechildren id="mainTree_treechildren">
    <treeitem container="true" open="true">
        <treerow>
           <treecell label="&tree.actions;" />
        </treerow>
        <treeitem container="true" open="true">
            <treerow>
                <treecell label="&tree.actions.warnings;" properties="warning" />
            </treerow>
        </treeitem>
     </treeitem>
</treechildren>
```

And the corresponding styles:

```css
#mainTree_treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text { color: #000000; }
#mainTree_treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(warning) { color: #FF0000; }
```

Note that using CSS selectors like `#foo #bar` isn't recommended - an ID is always unique so specifying more than one in a selector will only slow things down.